# mySQL Trigger Syntax - adding value to another table

Tags: mysql, triggers

i'm trying to figure out a way to automate my mysql database.

The database has several tables. The table logs contains raw log data from several devices (device_id, time, logs) and the tabele devices contains further information to a specific device identified by it's id, for example location, name and manufacturer.

Now I want to accomplish the following: Whenever new logs are imported into my logs table I want the database to automaticly check whether the device id is already registered in the devices table. If not I want it to be added.

I think this can be done with a trigger. After some research I came up with hthe following code, unfortunately i get an 1064 error: You have an error in your SQL syntax...

Is there anyone able to help me?

```
CREATE TRIGGER logs_after_insert AFTER INSERT ON logs
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE amount INT;
    SET amount = SELECT COUNT (*) FROM `devices` WHERE device_id = NEW.id GROUP BY device_id;
    IF (amount = 0) THEN
        INSERT INTO devices VALUES (NEW.device_id, , , , , );
    END IF;
END
```

The commas within the insert query are there cause I need to fill in the additional data to a device manually, for now I just want the id to be added and the other columns to be blank.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution by myself:

```
CREATE TRIGGER logs_after_insert AFTER INSERT ON logs
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT IGNORE INTO devices (device_id) VALUES (NEW.id);
END
```

Possibly not the best way to do it but for my case it's working just fine :)